# How to configure RestTemplate to be used with different URLs and Response Entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I defined a Configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

The bean above is used by different services to perform actions like these:

```
ResponseEntity<Cars> cars= restTemplate.exchange(
                                                     RequestEntity.get(new URI(url)).headers(headers).build(),
                                                    Cars.class);
```

or

```
ResponseEntity<CarDetail> savingAmountConsumed = restTemplate.exchange(
                                                            builder.buildAndExpand(uriVariable).toUri(),
                                                            HttpMethod.PUT,
                                                            requestEntity,
                                                            CarDetail.class);
```

For each service, I'm defining different URI variable `uriVariable` and always defining the same header configuration like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(token);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Is it possible to reconfigure the RestTemplate in a way that I don't need to set the same header in different services multiple times? (same question applies to the URI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the `Accept` header you can use an Interceptor as follows:

```java
public class AcceptHeaderSetterInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return execution.execute(request, body);
  }
}
```

Then you need to register this Interceptor:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
      restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new AcceptHeaderSetterInterceptor()));
      return restTemplate;
  }
}
```

Regarding the URI I wouldn't suggest you do that because it is pretty common to use the same `RestTemplate` to call different URLs. The same goes for the `Bearer Token` because I guess it really depends on the URL you are calling.

Comment: Thanks João! I've just came across the concept of Interceptor and added it directly in my Configuration class. For those interested, I'm using the same approach in the second example given here: `https://riptutorial.com/spring/example/24622/setting-headers-on-spring-resttemplate-request`